# How to store incoming data to database using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 and Automapper, as far as I learned, Automapper is to use saving time to map data one by one (please correct me if I'm mistaken). I have these entity classes in my `DbContext`:

```
public class FinLegCheckEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? CustomerRef { get; set; } = default!;
    public int KYClevel { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<PlatformKYCLevels> PlatformKycLevels { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }
}

public class PlatformKYCLevels
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; } = default!;
    public string MaxAmount { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

I built my database table based on the class above, and I have model classes, I use it when I get data from other service, so I need to map these two classes:

```
public class FinLegCheckModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? CustomerRef { get; set; } = default!;
    public int KYClevel { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<PlatformKYCLevels> PlatformKycLevels { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }
}

public class PlatformKYCLevels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; } = default!;
    public string MaxAmount { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Currency { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

I created a profile to map these two classes:

```
public class FinLegCheckProfile:Profile
{
    public FinLegCheckProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FinLegCheckEntity,FinLegCheckModel>();
    }
}
```

Well, I hope I'm in the right direction so far! So I get data from outside, if the data is already exist in the database I will update my db otherwise I will add, here is where I have a problem, how should I use Automapper:

```
var customerFincheckData = dbContext.FinLegCheckEntities.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CustomerId == fincheckdata.CustomerId);

if (customerFincheckData != null)
{
    customerFincheckData.CustomerId = fincheckdata.CustomerId;
    customerFincheckData.KYClevel = fincheckdata.KYClevel;
    customerFincheckData.PlatformKycLevels = fincheckdata.PlatformKycLevels;
    customerFincheckData.CustomerRef = fincheckdata.CustomerRef;
    customerFincheckData.Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                         
    dbContext.FinLegCheckEntities.Update(customerFincheckData);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
else
{
    var finlegEntities = new FinLegCheckEntity()
                             {
                                 CustomerId = fincheckdata.CustomerId,
                                 KYClevel = fincheckdata.KYClevel,
                                 PlatformKycLevels = fincheckdata.PlatformKycLevels,
                                 CustomerRef = fincheckdata.CustomerRef,
                                 Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                                 Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                              };
    dbContext.FinLegCheckEntities.Add(finlegEntities);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

I have injected `IMapper` into the class and i have access to `_mapper.Map` but the problem is how can store or update the db after mapping?

Comment: In my opinion, out of topic, I will suggest avoid automapper.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli why and if i dont use ,i get error when i want to put model into entity,how to sort that?

Comment: in my experience, automapper is good for programming fast, but it will generate a lot of functional problems in the future. There is no so consumption of time if you work with every field mapping in a repository with every property of your own businness model. I like to work by hand this, but, again, is my personal opinion not related to your question. There is such debate about automapper :)

Comment: @LeandroBardelli thanks for your openion,but lets say i dont use automapper,how do you sort the above issue?i get mapping error in this part PlatformKycLevels = fincheckdata.PlatformKycLevels,,it says cant convert FinLegCheckModel to FinLegCheckEntity

Comment: What do you need DTO for? I am usually using DTO for a grid view only, when I need 3-4 properties ( that should be created by join in any case), but the main class has 10 times more than I need.

Comment: Well, we had to see what is FinLegCheckEntities, it can be that you are mixing models? You are using classes with the same name of intances for properties that can be a bit confusing and provoque some errors at the moment of the mapping

Comment: @Serge I just get data from another service and want to store in the DB,i dont need model you mean? i should directly put data in my Entity class?

Comment: @moris62 I posted my suggestions.

Comment: It's not wrong to use a DTO. Some patterns (such as Clean Architecture) expect entity models to remain separate. They don't get exposed all the way to the API layer. It's ultimately a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need any DTO since it is the same as an entity class. But in any case try this code. You can remap your data before using it.

```
public bool AddOrUpdateFinLegCheckEntity (FinLegCheckEntity model)
{
if ( model.CustomerId > 0 )
{
var existedFincheckData = dbContext.FinLegCheckEntities.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CustomerId == model.CustomerId);

  if (existedFincheckData != null)
  {
    model.Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    
   dbContext.Entry(existedFincheckData).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
  } else return false;
}
else
{
    model.Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
     model.Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
     dbContext.FinLegCheckEntities.Add(model);
}
 dbContext.SaveChanges();

......
return true;
}
```

Comment: Some patterns call for separating entity models though, such that entity models are not visible to all layers and are instead restricted to a data layer or service layer. They're not exposed to the API layer.

Comment: @MattU thanks for a feedback. It is just my suggestion since I use algorithm like this. But maybe it need to be corrected. I can't  see any views, and get and post actions. Only after this I can offer the more certain code.

Comment: thanks a lost ,just have two questions, dbContext.Entry(existedFincheckData).CurrentValues.SetValues(model) does the update?my scecond question is,we need Models only if we want to pass data to another service or UI?because in the cleanArchitecture we have Model inside core

Comment: Im getting data frim azureBus and store in the DB

Comment: @moris62 are you implementing Clean Architecture? If so, you should definitely not be exposing your entity models all the way up the stack. In fact, it should be designed in a way that explicitly forbids that.

Comment: @MattU yes im trying to implement clean architecture ,thats why im not sure should i use models and mappers?or directly bind my Entityclass and store in the DB?i get data from azurebus and want to store it,am i missing something?

Comment: @MattU You have to post the whole code, we should not guess  how you obtain data to save. I just offered you some code to save data. It doesn' t matter what do you use before or after. You can map anything before saving.

Comment: @Serge to be honest i love the code you have written,saved lines of unnecessary code,the only question I have is,should i use always Model?(suggested by clean architecture)?or i should use model when i want to send data to UI or pass to other services?

Comment: I agree that's likely a whole different question / discussion. How to go about updating data in Clean Architecture is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @moris62 I am sorry , but I don' t know what is  a Clean Architecture,  for me it is just another buzz word, and it is out of scope  of your question. I use DTO very rare, only in special occasions. But as I told , I just suggested an algorithm, and it is up to you to use it.  You can map from dto to entity before using this code, if you still want to use DTOs.